# Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirecotry not useful when set StartInfo.Verb = "runas" to start .bat file(contain cd command)

Tags: c#, process

Background: I want use C# program to call a bat file which will goto next different folders then execute different exe.

Here is the test.bat file:

```
echo test begin

cd test1
setup1.exe

cd test2
setup2.exe

echo test finished
echo off
```

And here is my C# Code:

```
using (Process proc = new Process())
{
    string command = @"c:\users\danvy\Desktop\script\test.bat";
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = command;
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(command);

    //run as admin
    proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

    proc.Start();
    while (!proc.HasExited)
    {
        proc.WaitForExit(1000);
    }
}
```

In this case, setup1.exe and setup2.exe can't be implemented.

But if comment line: proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
Then, setup1.exe and setup2.exe can be called to run.

That's so strange, seems like when set proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; the WorkingDirectory is not working.

In my opinion, Verb = "runas" only to set privilege to let program run as Administartor, why it will make Process.StartInfo.WorkingDirecotry not useful?

Comment: This is "by design". Try to run `cmd.exe` as admin and you will see that you are "moved" to `%WINDIR%/system32/` folder.

Comment: So if Verb = "runas", then WorkingDirectory is changed to "%WINDIR%/system32/", and no way to change it?

Comment: Yes, and again: this is "by-design" (design of OS). You must not fight against it.

Comment: @vasily.sib, thank you very much.

Comment: One way you can handle this is invoke some kind of this: `cmd.exe /c "cd PLACE_YOUR_WORKING_DIR_HERE && test.bat"`

Comment: @vasily.sib, that's a good way, I just tried, it works. Thanks.